# How to fill inn A, B, C ...Y, Z, A, B, ...Y, Z, A, B, and so on?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

as a second part of a problem i am trying to solve. I need help to figure out how to fill in serial letters.. Starting at A.. going to Z and starting over at A again.. I have a tabel with numbers 1-600 and i want 1 to be A, 2 = B, .... 26= Z, 27 = A 28 = B and repeating like that....

I am using field calculator in ArcMap.

Alternatively, how to create the numbers 1-26 over and over.. so.. 1, 2, 3, ...25, 26, 1, 2, 3.. and so on..

Answer (score 4):

Regarding alternatively:

Code block:

```
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
 global rec
 pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd 
 pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
 if (rec == 0): 
  rec = pStart 
 elif (rec==26):
  rec = 1 
 else: 
  rec = rec + pInterval 
 return rec
```

Field_Name:

```
autoIncrement()
```